# How to access data in the modal from button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

```
{individual && individual.map((el)=>{
    return (
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive-modal"  className="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-t-20">UnSubscribe</a>
      <div id="responsive-modal" className="modal fade emp-add-list" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style={{display: "none"}}>
                 <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">

                       <div className="modal-body">
                          <div className="form-group">
                               <div className="checkbox">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.withdrawPlan.bind(this, el)}>Withdraw Plan</button>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

     )
         })
 }





  withdrawPlan(el){
    let data = {
        subscription_plan_id: 'SP5bd18b12b144f81f341a72ed',
        reason: this.state.withdrawl_reason
    }
    UserAction._planWithdrawl(data);
}
```

I am having a button to `unsubscribe` from unsubscribe i can get all the `el` data, how to access that `el` data in the modal, on click of withdrawplan I need to access the el data.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding it correctly.
Firstly why are you having method in template?

You dont need anchor tag. you can have data in modal via function

```
<button href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive-modal" onClick={()=>this.myFunction(el)} className="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-t-20">UnSubscribe</button>
```

In my function save the data in state and trigger the modal from there. Your state should be like

this.state = {
 enableModal: false,
 data: null
}

Comment: what is myFunction, IN that what will be there

Comment: IN my function i can access el but in the modal we are having button , from that button how to access that el

Comment: Thats because your modal is outside of individual.map function. You have to keep it inside the loop just like unsubscribe.

Comment: @sivasai081 have you tried 
<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>this.withdrawPlan(el)}>Withdraw Plan</button>

You need to bind withdrawPlan in constructor
this.his.withdrawPlan = this.his.withdrawPlan.bind(this)

Comment: instead of this
 onClick={this.withdrawPlan.bind(this, el)
try this
onClick={()=>this.withdrawPlan(el)}

Comment: I tried, but all the time i am able to get the first id only all the time